# Skype Number on SIP Profile not Ringing on PBX

Tags: sip, voip, skype, pbx

I have purchased a Skype Online Number on a SIP Profile from Skype Manager. I've setup the Authentication Settings on my Yeastar Standard PBX. I have also activated a subscription for '1 Channel' on the SIP profile.

The SIP Profile shows as 'Registered' on both the PBX and on 'Skype Manager'.

When i call the Online Number from my mobile, it rings then 'hangs up' but never on the PBX or the extension assigned to the number. Is there anything i'm doing wrong on the setup or do i need to activate the Online Number somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the 'Incoming Number' section on the PBX. Skype requires that the Online number include the country code for the number.